# JWPlayer alternatives that allow custom skinning and rtmp streaming (via amazon cloud front)?

Tags: video, streaming, jwplayer

Anyone have any viable alternatives to the JWPlayer.  I need to customize the player skin, and allow rtmp streaming (via amazon cloudfront).  I originally purchased the JWPlayer 6 pro license for a one time cost of 99 dollars, and now it is a 99 annual cost.  Any suggestions on other alternatives?

Comment: If you purchased JW Player 6 when it was a one time cost, you are still locked in to that license agreement. Your player purchase is still a one time cost.

Comment: You can contact us to confirm this, as well - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased JW Player 6 when it was a one time cost, you are still locked in to that license agreement. Your player purchase is still a one time cost.

You can contact us to confirm this, as well - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: My biggest issue is with a development project I started with a client is now almost at production. All this work was done at an assumed cost of 99 perpetual, and it flipped in Jan to an annual charge.  I'm trying to ascertain how many licenses will need to be purchased long term, and what other options are available.  If the original pricing of 99 perpetual was honored, it would be a no brainer.

Comment: If you log into your JW Player account, you will see that the license that you purchased it one time. You are grandfathered in to the old licensing model.